# Weird react when using SetTimeout for Each function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I use setTimeout function to add a delay to an effect when running each function in JavaScript.

The first loop run well, however, after you scroll up and scroll down again, there is a glitch on the icons.

**HTML code**

```
<div id="box"></div>
<div class="service-modules-section">
  <div class="service-modules">
    <div class="half service-row-left">

      <div class="service-item">
        <div class="icon-wrap">
          <img alt="Canadian News Reporting Icon" class="img-fluid" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/vcferreira/firefox-os/128/sms-icon.png" style="display: inline;" width=50px>
        </div>
        <div class="service-meta">
          <h3>News Reporting</h3>
          <p>From breaking national, regional and world news to the biggest events in politics, sports, business and entertainment, we are there when it matters, delivering news about Canadians to Canadians, 24/7.ok.</p>            </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>  
      <div class="service-item">
        <div class="icon-wrap">
          <img alt="Canadian News Reporting Icon" class="img-fluid" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/vcferreira/firefox-os/128/sms-icon.png" style="display: inline;" width=50px>
        </div>
        <div class="service-meta">
          <h3>News Reporting</h3>
          <p>From breaking national, regional and world news to the biggest events in politics, sports, business and entertainment, we are there when it matters, delivering news about Canadians to Canadians, 24/7.ok.</p>            </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>  
      <div class="service-item">
        <div class="icon-wrap">
          <img alt="Canadian News Reporting Icon" class="img-fluid" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/vcferreira/firefox-os/128/sms-icon.png" style="display: inline;" width=50px>
        </div>
        <div class="service-meta">
          <h3>News Reporting</h3>
          <p>From breaking national, regional and world news to the biggest events in politics, sports, business and entertainment, we are there when it matters, delivering news about Canadians to Canadians, 24/7.ok.</p>            </div>              
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
#box {
  height: 600px;
}
.service-modules-section{
  position: relative;
}
img {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
}
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
var speed = 500;  
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: $('.icon-wrap').children(),
  handler: function(direction) {     
      $('.icon-wrap').children().each(function(k, v){
        var el = this;
        setTimeout(function (){
          $(el).animate({
        'opacity': '70'
    }, {
        step: function (now, fx) {          
            $(el).css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, " + -now + "px, 0px)"});
        },
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false,
        complete: function () {
            // alert('Animation is done');
        }
    }, 'linear');

    $(el).animate({ textIndent: 100 }, {
        duration : 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    });   
        }, k*speed);                        

    })  

    if(direction === "up"){
      $('.icon-wrap').children().css('top', '100px');
    }
  },  offset: '75%'
});
```

Any ideas to what happens? Thanks,

https://codepen.io/techcater/pen/jwJZZe

Comment: Likely a scope or closure issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840106/settimeout-in-a-jquery-animation

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, I will take a look at that.

Comment: Try changing var el... to let el...

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus. I tried. I'm not sure what makes a difference between var el and let el in this situation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this by giving the condition when scrolling up and down.

```
var speed = 500;
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: $('.icon-wrap').children(),
  handler: function(direction) {
    if(direction === "down"){
      $('.icon-wrap').children().each(function(k, v){
        var el = this;

        setTimeout(function (){
          $(el).animate({
            'opacity': '65'
          }, {
            step: function (now, fx) {
              $(el).css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, " + -now + "px, 0px)"});
            },
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false,
            complete: function () {
            }
          }, 'linear');

          $(el).animate({ textIndent: 100 }, {
            duration : 1000,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
          });
        }, k*speed);

      });
    }

    if(direction === "up"){
      $('.icon-wrap').children().css({"opacity": "0"});
    }
  },  offset: '75%'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable to check if animation is completed. If not, evaluate the animation and if yes, don't do anythin.

JS Code Fixed:

```
var speed = 500;
var completed = false;
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: $('.icon-wrap').children(),
  handler: function(direction) {
    if (!completed) {
      $('.icon-wrap').children().each(function(k, v){
        var el = this;
        setTimeout(function (){
          $(el).animate({
        'opacity': '70'
    }, {
        step: function (now, fx) {          
            $(el).css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, " + -now + "px, 0px)"});
        },
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false,
        complete: function () {
             completed = true;
        }
    }, 'linear');

    $(el).animate({ textIndent: 100 }, {
        duration : 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    });   
        }, k*speed);                        

    })  

    if(direction === "up"){
      $('.icon-wrap').children().css('top', '100px');
    }
    }
  },  offset: '75%'

});
```

Comment: Hi @xF4B, thanks for the fix. This fix works fine but it only runs once. When I re-scroll it, there is no more effect to this.